# How to get the position of the highest value in a row of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, row

I need to create a program that, given a matrix, asks for a row in the matrix and gives the position of the highest value in that row.

For example with the matrix:

```
D = [(0 1 3),
     (1 0 4),
     (3 4 0)]
```

when given the value 2 should return 1 (because in the row[2] the highest value is 4 which is in position 1 in that row).

Right now I'm trying:

```
def farthest(matrix, row, point):
    maxdist = 0
    matrix2 = []
    for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
        if i == int(point):
            matrix2.append(i)
        if i != int(point):
            pass
        for j in range(0, len(matrix2)):
            if j < maxdist :
                pass
            if j > maxdist:
                maxdist = maxdist + j
    print(matrix2)
    print(maxdist)
    return matrix2
```

I should find a solution using loops.
The current output that I get is [2] and [0].

Comment: You have told us what the desired output is. You haven't told us what the actual output is. What output does your program produce? If it throws an error what is the error?

Comment: i just edited it. Thanks

Comment: What do you think the following does `if j > maxdist:`? Don't you want to compare to the value at the position to the previous max value not to the position?

Comment: Yes. So how should it be? Because I can't seem to get it right. Thanks

Comment: Try adding some print statements into your code as it runs. Before you start the `j` loop `print(str(matrix2))` will tell you what `j` is going to loop on. Before you do the `if j < maxdist :` test add `print('j = ' + int(j) + ' :: maxdist = ' + int(maxdist))`. That will tell you what is happening in that loop. Those outputs should give you some good clues as to what is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: it is somehow not helping at all. I do not know how to make ask for the value of j or i and not just the position

Comment: Get the first value in the row `maxvalue = j[0]`. Now you have something to compare to the value at `j[1]`. If `j[1]` is greater than `maxvalue` then set `maxvalue` to `j[1]`. Go onwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy and `argmax` for axis 1 for this, to get the position of the maximum value per row.

```
import numpy as np

D = [(0, 1, 3),
     (1, 0, 4),
     (3, 4, 0)]

t = np.array(D).argmax(axis=1)
t
```

Which will give you

```
array([2, 2, 1])
```

Can can then index with the row you are after

```
t[2]
1
```

Comment: the problem is that i'm not supposed to know how numpy or argmax works. I should be able to find a solution using loops. thanks